# brownie is not reading web3 infura project id even though it's already set in .env

Tags: erc-721, nft, brownie

I'm following Patrick Collins' NFT Smart Contract course on YT and I can't get Brownie to read the  WEB3 Infura project id

This is what the Error looks like

```
    Brownie v1.16.4 - Python development framework for Ethereum
  File "C:\Users\Mohid, line Shahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\__main__.py", in 64
    importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()
  File "C:\Users\Mohid, line Shahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", in 43     
    network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])
  File "C:\Users\Mohid, line Shahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py", in 40 
    web3.connect(host, active.get("timeout", 30))
  File "C:\Users\Mohid, line Shahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", in 52 
    uri = _expand_environment_vars(uri)
  File "C:\Users\Mohid, line Shahid\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\brownie\network\web3.py", in 183
    raise ValueError(f"Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: '{uri}'")
ValueError: Unable to expand environment variable in host setting: 'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/$WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID'
```

I've set up my variable in the `.env` file correctly and verified that `brownie-config.yaml` file has `dotenv: .env`in it.

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Thank you

EDIT: Got it working, I accidentally cloned the project in the .brownie folder in C Drive. After cloning it somewhere else on the other drive it's working fine

Comment: What's the content of `brownie-config.yaml`?